# So what happens to Judaism if Moshiach doesn't come by the year 6000?

Tags: talmud-gemara, messiah, talmud-bavli

Since it says in the Talmud that Moshiach has to come by the year 6000, so what happens to Judaism if Moshiach doesn't come by the year 6000.

The year 6000 view comes from the Babylonian Talmud, Sanhedrin 97a. The Talmud compares the messianic age to the Sabbath and note that a day to God is like a thousand years. So Sunday (0-1000), Monday (1000-2000), Tuesday (2000-3000), Wednesday (3000-4000), Thursday (4000-5000), Friday (5000-6000), and Shabbat (6000-7000).

It has been taught in accordance with R. Kattina: "Just as the seventh year is one year of release in seven, so is the world: one thousand years out of seven shall be fallow, as it is written, 'And the Lord alone shall be exalted in that day,' and it is further said, 'A Psalm and song for the Sabbath day,' (Ps. 92:1) meaning the day that is altogether Sabbath — and it is also said, 'For a thousand years in thy sight are but as yesterday when it is past' (Ps. 90:4)."
2

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you believe that the Talmud means this literally, then the question doesn't start, because the messiah **will** arrive by 6000. Asking what will happen if he doesn't is like asking what happened when the sun didn't rise this morning. And if you think the Talmud is speaking metaphorically then the question doesn't start either.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but this 'Keitz' wasn't set by human beings as far as I am aware. This is part of G-d's arrangement, just like the idea that giving of the Torah had to be when it was. The pressing nature of Matan Torah is emphasized in regard to the subject of descending to the 49th gate of 'tumah', etc.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67507/759

Comment: @msh210 `If you believe that the Talmud means this literally, then the question doesn't start, because the messiah will arrive by 6000` Nope. The Talmud could be literal, but still be wrong. As Rambam teaches us [about this in particular](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76317/8775) and as [the general consensus of Jewish sources indicate](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351).

Comment: Doesn’t that same Gemara say that we don’t have a tradition regarding the days of Mashiach beyond what’s written in Tanach? So if 6000 is wrong, that just means we misread those incredibly dense verses. Also, note how many other dates in that Gemara have passed. Finally, it’s a three-way debate in that Gemara as to what brings Mashiach - Rav holds *only* good deeds, Shmuel holds *only* the Keitz, and R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi holds that there is a Keitz but we can cause Mashiach to come early with good deeds. So if Rav is correct then this question is moot. (Con’t)

Comment: Those dates mentioned above are cited throughout both sides of Sanhedrin 97. Rav and Shmuel’s opinions are toward the bottom of 97b, while R’ Yehoshua Ben Levi’s is cited on 98a (regarding בעיתה אחכישנה and היום אם בקולו תשמעו).

Comment: we continue as before as there does not seem to be any reason moshiach must come by the year 6000 specifically as an aboslute fact. There is much that isn't understood entirely about the time of moshiach and while learning about it intensifies our desire (a mitzvah to be actively awaiting his coming) as far as when he will come, "the hidden things are for Hashem". That being said may we merit to see his coming immediately and not have to wait any longer.

Answer (score 6):

It would mean absolutely nothing. All it would mean is that we (living in what we think is year 6000) either miscounted or (those who wrote the medrash) misinterpreted what was going on. Many people have guessed when the mashiach would arrive and been wrong. Consider the division of the ages of the worls into two thousand year epochs in which the birth of Avraham (1948), Yitzchak (2048) or Yaakov (2108) are considered the end of the first epoch. The dates in such calculations are only approximate.

All we can say is that when someone appears to have met the criteria for mashiach, then we would be willing to accept him. If he fails or dies, then admit that he wasn't and go on. Look at the trouble Shabtai Tzvi and his predecessors for the past several thousand years have caused.

Rambam does not set the time at 6000 years. He says Hashem will send Mashiach when He has determined to. We are guessing about 6000 years. Indeed consider the problem if it actually means 6001 (1 - 1000, 1001 - 2000, ... 5001 - 6000) and people get upset about mashiach not coming in 6000 Or indeed, consider the upset if people are off in when during the year. Chet Haeigel occurred because of a one day miscalculation.

[Rambam Hilchos melachim 12:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188357/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-12.htm) says

> Regardless of the debate concerning these questions, neither the order
>   of the occurrence of these events or their precise detail are among
>   the fundamental principles of the faith. A person should not occupy
>   himself with the Aggadot and homiletics concerning these and similar
>   matters, nor should he consider them as essentials, for study of them
>   will neither bring fear or love of God.
>
> Similarly, one should not try to determine the appointed time for
>   Mashiach's coming. Our Sages declared: 'May the spirits of those who
>   attempt to determine the time of Mashiach's coming expire!' Rather,
>   one should await and believe in the general conception of the matter
>   as explained.

There is a quip that the prohibition did not stop the Rambam from speculating.

As it says [When Will the Mashiach Come?](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/jewfaq/mashiach.htm#When)

> There is a wide variety of opinions on the subject of when the
>   mashiach will come.  Some of the Jews' greatest minds have cursed
>   those who try to predict the time of the mashiach's coming, because
>   errors in such predictions could cause people to lose faith in the
>   messianic idea or in the Torah itself.  This actually happened in the
>   17th century, when Shabbtai Tzvi claimed to be the mashiach; when Tzvi
>   converted to Islam under threat of death, many Jews converted with
>   him.  Nevertheless, this "prohibition" has not stopped anybody from
>   speculating about the time when the mashiach will come (including some
>   who themselves spoke harshly of those who engaged in such vain
>   efforts!).
>
> Although some scholars believed that God has set aside a specific date
>   for the coming of the mashiach, most authorities suggest that the
>   conduct of mankind will determine the time of the mashiach's coming. 
>   In general, it is believed that the mashiach will come in a time when
>   he is most needed (because the world is so evil), or in a time when he
>   is most deserved (because the world is so good).  For example, each of
>   the following has been suggested as the time when the mashiach will
>   come:
>
> - when all Israel repent a single day
> - when all Israel observe a single sabbath properly
> - when all Israel observe two sabbaths in a row properly
> - in a generation that is totally innocent, or totally guilty
> - in a generation that loses hope
> - in a generation where children are totally disrespectful towards their parents and elders (commonly thought to be "our generation", in
>     every generation!)

Comment: The discussion you bring from Rambam is talking about setting a time limit within the framework set by Torah, meaning 'it will occur by this date and time within the boundary laid out in the Torah. In other words, early or late, "B'Itah, Achisheina". In merit it is hastened (Achisheina). If not, in its time (B'Itah). The framework of Torah sets the limit (B'Itah) at 6000 years less the time that one is required to take on Shabbat. It doesn't mean there is no boundary or time limit at all.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Rambam does not set the time at 6000 years. He says Hashem will send Mashiach when He has determined to. We are guessing about 6000 years. Indeed consider the problem if it actually means 6001 (1 - 100, 1001 - 2000, ... 5001 - 6000) and people get upset about mashiach not coming in 6000 Or indeed, consider the upset if people are off in when during the year. Chet Haeigel occurred because of a one day miscalculation.

Comment: Rambam, in the Mishnah Torah you quote, is silent on this subject. What source are you using that says the 6000 year limit is a speculation. There is a comment in the Aggadic portion of Shas that talks about going beyond the 6000 year limit for Moshiach which is dismissed. This is also discussed by Ramchal in Sefer Pinot HaMerkava and Sefer Brit Menucha by Rabbi Avraham of Rimon. They explain that beyond the year 6000 is talking about Olam HaBa, the World of Resurrection, not the coming Moshiach, meaning 'the Days of Moshiach'.

Comment: @YaacovDeane By definition IF Rambam was aware of the Talmud giving a 6000 year date (which he certainly was) AND is silent on the subject AND subsequently said there is no definite date, THEN the Rambam clearly holds that the 6000 years date is not a literal, absolute date OR is not referencing what we think, which is covered in this answer as well: *"All it would mean is that we either miscounted or misinterpreted what was going on."*

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky You were good for your first two assumptions. In dealing with halacha, and specifically in regard to the Mishnah Torah, the convention to understanding the meaning of the text is that if there is silence regarding a stated position, it is assumed the author and/or commentators are in agreement with it. That means that Rambam agrees that there is a 6000 year limit to the coming of Moshiach, which is the accepted viewpoint in Shas.

Comment: Note as well that the year 5776 is just a popular convention following one Midrashic opinion. Even assuming Bereishit 1 is strictly literal, we can only know the correct year to +/- a few hundred.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Isaac's point is that it is not the case that "there is silence regarding a stated position". Rather Rambam explicitly says there is no definite date. Hence he does't accept 6000 as a fixed limit.

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm not going to rehash this idea. The general rule in regard to Mishnah Torah is 'if there is silence, meaning no rejection, regarding a stated position, it is assumed the author and/or commentators are in agreement with that position.' There is a comment in the Aggadic portion of Shas that considers about going beyond the 6000 year time limit for Moshiach which is dismissed. Rambam does not reject this. Which means that Rambam's comment of 'no definite time limit' means at the year 6000 or before. Not after. If you choose to believe otherwise, that is you prerogative.

Comment: @YaacovDeane Actually, Rambam does reject that, as he says "no definite time limit" (or whatever the language is).

Comment: @DoubleAA That is not a rejection. It is a clarification of the accepted view.

Comment: @YaacovDeane No, it's a statement of the accepted view. You don't clarify an exception without stating what it's an exception to.

Answer (score 1):

It would mean nothing for Judaism. It would just mean that that particular Midrash [was wrong](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351). This would be no surprise, since [(according to the vast majority of Geonim and Rishonim)](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53349/belief-in-midrashim/53351#53351) the Midrashim are not based on tradition but are at most the personal views of individual scholars. Everyone can be wrong.

In the words of Dr. David Berger:

> I am more than a bit disturbed when respected Orthodox organizations disseminate material stating as undeniable fact that the redemption must come
>   before  the  year  6,000  in  the  Jewish  calendar.  Other  messianic dates  in  the Talmud  have  passed,  and  Maimonides—in  an  explicit  effort  to  discourage messianic  calculation  and  obsession—made  a  point  of  emphasizing  that even  Hazal  did  not  have  a  tradition  regarding  these  matters  (Hilkhot Melakhim 12:2). Many years ago, a friend told me how a classmate of his in a  traditionalist  yeshiva  had  told  him  that  if  he  would  be  alive  in  the  year 6,000 and the Messiah would not have come, he would throw his tefillin on the  ground  and  stomp  on  them.  It  is  worth  reemphasizing  the  prophet’s declaration:  “For  My  thoughts  are  not  your  thoughts,  nor  are  My  ways your ways, declares the Lord. But as the heavens are high above the earth, so  are  My  ways  high  above  your  ways,  and  my  thoughts  above  your thoughts” (Isaiah 55:8-9). [1]

---

[1] [TRADITION 39:2 (2005)](http://traditionarchive.org/news/_pdfs/berger.pdf)  p. 77 note 2.