# Weird Weather Before Mashiach

Tags: sources-mekorot, messiah, weather

With Harvey and Irma and the Mexican earthquakes and the recent solar eclipse, it’s often been quoted recently that there will be weird weather before Mashiach comes. This is nothing new for me - I’ve grown up hearing about this Midrash, which has invariably been applied when there’s weird weather. However, when I actually go look for it, I can’t seem to find it. Has anyone heard of this before, and can they refer me to it? Thanks!

Comment: Remember that [no one actually knows](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76317/8775) what will happen before the arrival of the messiah...

Comment: @mevaqesh Sure, but several Midrashim are out there on the topic nevertheless.

Comment: I've heard it too. But I don't know if it's a midrash or just something my mother says. :) Which she could be right...But I dunno.