# Does the resurrection of the dead have to begin by the year 5790

Tags: messiah, resurrection-of-the-dead

Does the resurrection of the dead have to begin by the year 5790?

RESURRECTION IN 13 YEARS TIME

According to [Aish.com](http://www.aish.com/jw/s/48883092.html):

> the Zohar (Midrash Ne'elam - Toldot 140a), and the "Leshem Shevo v'Achlamah"(Drushei Olam HaTohu, 2:4:12:9-12) -- that suggest that this period will begin no later than 210 years in advance of Year 6000.

That's 13 years from today!

As stated on the [Yeshivaworldcoffeeroom](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/world-events):

> but Techiyas HaMeisim will last 210 years, which brings us to the latest possible time Techiyas HaMeisim can come as 5790, which is only 13 years away!

Comment: I believe I reconstructed the sources for the passages you quoted unattributed. If you quoted them from some other source, consider editing to clarify. Sources for cited passages should be identified.

Comment: What is the point for the final paragraph? What does it add to the first quote?

Comment: Whats the question exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mashiach in year 6000?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/67507/mashiach-in-year-6000)

Answer (score 5):

No the resurrection does not **need** to begin by a certain 5790, or any other specific date. Eschatological predictions are matters of personal conjecture; not definitive views of Judaism.

In the words of Dr. David Berger:

> I am more than a bit disturbed when respected Orthodox organizations disseminate material stating as undeniable fact that the redemption must come
>   before  the  year  6,000  in  the  Jewish  calendar.  Other  messianic dates  in  the Talmud  have  passed,  and  Maimonides—in  an  explicit  effort  to  discourage messianic  calculation  and  obsession—made  a  point  of  emphasizing  that even  Hazal  did  not  have  a  tradition  regarding  these  matters  ([Hilkhot Melakhim 12:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1188357/jewish/Melachim-uMilchamot-Chapter-12.htm)). Many years ago, a friend told me how a classmate of his in a  traditionalist  yeshiva  had  told  him  that  if  he  would  be  alive  in  the  year 6,000 and the Messiah would not have come, he would throw his tefillin on the  ground  and  stomp  on  them.  It  is  worth  reemphasizing  the  prophet’s declaration:  “For  My  thoughts  are  not  your  thoughts,  nor  are  My  ways your ways, declares the Lord. But as the heavens are high above the earth, so  are  My  ways  high  above  your  ways,  and  my  thoughts  above  your thoughts” (Isaiah 55:8-9). [i]

This would apply to the 6000 year mark from which they are counting back the years for the resurrection of the dead, in addition to the point at which the resurrection itself would begin.

---

[I]Tradition: A Journal of Orthodox Jewish Thought Vol 39 No. 2, p 77, note 2. 
https://www.jstor.org/stable/23262886?seq=12#metadata_info_tab_contents