# Are there any opinions of a deadline for Moshiach later than the year 6000?

Tags: talmud-gemara, calendar, messiah

As discussed [on this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/67507/), there are Talmudic opinions (e.g. in Rosh Hashana 31a and Sanhedrin 97a) that Moshiach must be here by the year 6000 AM (whether stated explicitly about Moshiach or whether indirectly by saying the world as we know it will last only 6000 years), which is a widely-accepted belief. However, [answers on this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/76310/) indicate that it is not fundamentally required to believe that the deadline is correct.

With that in mind, are there any opinions of a specific deadline for Moshiach set *after* the year 6000? For example, is there any opinion in the Talmud or rabbinic writings that Moshiach has to be here by the year 7000, or 60000? I do not mean whether there are opinions about taking years non-literally, but rather whether there are explicit opinions indicating a specific deadline later than 6000.

Comment: Ramban ( somewhere) says that mashiach era has to be around for at least 200 years. So he has to come before 5800

Comment: "that Moshiach must be here by the year 6000" no, that's the date for the end of the times of Moshiach, meaning, he will already be he long before

Comment: @Shlomy Perhaps not everyone agrees with Ramban about the minimum duration that the messianic era must exist? I'd be interested in a source if you can find one, and if you can find that there is widespread consensus about that I may amend my question. At any rate, be it the deadline for the start or end of the messianic era, I'm asking whether the 6000 year deadline is the latest rabbinical opinion stated.

Comment: @AL It seems that generally speaking, the non "6000" views don't have any limit.

Comment: given the scarcity of this point of view (the two references in the gemara that you cite), this singular position may have become inflated over time. Some people may take it literally, whereas it could have been originally considered more figuratively. Who knows. Few early commentaries discuss it which could mean that there is little consensus on the alleged "hard deadline" of 6000 years.